# How to connect Spring Cloud Data Cloud and ADFS server using OAuth2

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have known that Spring CLoud Data Flow used UAA and LDAP to deploy security feature. However,
is it possible if following this [link](https://github.com/amitmisra16/adfs-oauth2-poc/tree/master/ui-adfs/src/main) to configure Spring Security OAuth2 Resource/Authorization Server?

Are these any better way to develop security feature of Spring Cloud Data Flow using ADFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the client configuration (at SCDF) involved in connecting to the OAuth2 Resource/Authorization Server, you can refer the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-spring-security-oauth2-example).
I am not sure about how this will play out ADFS but feel free to try these OAuth2 configuration and create any issues/feature requests on Spring Cloud Data Flow [GH](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow).

There is also a [GH story](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3712) in place to try this on AAD.